# Too many HashedWheelTimer error in Spark application

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I met this error when running spark streaming application. This error happened only once and the application has been running over 500 hours.

Here are some dependencies and their versions: 
Spark: 1.5.1
Spark-Cassandra-Connector 1.5.0-M3

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Akka actors or the Akka scheduler in your app? It would help if you added some relevant code.

Comment: No, i don't use any Akka stuff